# C++ Qt - Ui::Window and inheritance / Forward declaration

Tags: qt

I am implementing a card game. I want the window `ui` to be an object of class `Rule`, so that `Rule` can modify the GUI directly.

So `Rule` has an object `Window * ui` initialized in the constructor.

But during compilation, the compiler tells me that in `rule.h`, "Window has not been declared", "Window is not a type". I included `<window.h>`, everything has the same type, everything is initialized, so I run out of ideas of why it does not work.

EDIT: I edited the code following alexisdm's notes. In addition, in `rule.h`, I had to change the definition of `ui` from `Window * ui` to `Ui::Window *ui`, because in `window.h`, `ui` is defined as `Ui::Window * ui`, and this is the object I want `Rule::rule` to control.

But now, in rule.cpp, `ui->do_stuff()` does not compile, because `Ui::Window` does not have the `do_stuff()` function, but `Window` does...

Arg! What to do?!! ui->do_stuff() works fine in window.cpp. Inheritance problem?

window.cpp:

```
    Window::Window(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Window)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    player = new Game_state();                  /* Game state                   */
    rule = new Rule(player, ui);                /* Implement the action of cards*/
}
void Window::do_stuff(){
//Do stuff
}
```

window.h

```
#include <QDialog>
#include "game_state.h"
#include "rule.h"

class Rule;
namespace Ui {
    class Window;
}

class Window : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Window();
    Game_state      * player;
    Rule            * rule;
    void do_stuff();

private:
    Ui::Window *ui;
};
```

rule.h

```
#ifndef RULE_H
#define RULE_H
#include "window.h"
#include <game_state.h>

class Window;

class Rule{
public:
    Rule(Game_state *, Ui::Window *);
    void action(Card *);

private:
    Game_state * player;
    Ui::Window     * ui;
};


#endif // RULE_H
```

rule.cpp

```
    #include <rule.h>

    Rule::Rule(Game_state * game, Ui::Window * window){
        player = game;
        ui = window;
    }
    void Rule::stuff(){
        ui->do_stuff();
    }
```

Comment: Please attach window.h, otherwise it's difficult to analyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a circular dependency in your headers: `window.h` and `rule.h` are referencing each other.

You should replace both `#include` by forward declarations to avoid it.

```
class Window;  // instead of #include "window.h"
class Rule;  // instead of #include "rule.h"
```

You'll still need to add `#include "window.h"` in `rule.cpp`, and `#include "rule.h"` in `window.cpp`.

Comment: What is a forward declaration? EDIT: How to use forward declaration in the case of variables?

Comment: You should also use include guards in your headers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: @NikosC. The include guards are already present, or there would be "multiple definitions" errors. Edit: He just didn't include them in his question, as he didn't know what the problem was...

Comment: @Bibi541 What do you mean by "in the case of variables" ?

Comment: @NikosC.: I have include guards, I just did not include them in the code, alexisdm is right.

alexisdm: I used forward declaration for the case where a program  has two functions A and B. If function A calls function B, and function B calls function A, then there’s no way to order the functions in a way that they will both be happy. I never used it in the case of variables (Window * ui/ Rule * rule).

Comment: @Bibi541 You can forward declare types that you use only as pointer, reference or function parameter, as long as you don't access the pointed data, which is usually done in the .cpp file where you'll need to use the `#include`. See that [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/553869/894321) for details.

Comment: I updated the code in my question, and reading this other answer made me understand the error the compiler is giving me. Since I can't access/modify the data inside an incomplete type, if I use a forward declaration, this mean that I won't be able to access the data, ever.

Therefore, for the use I intend, I should change my architecture, and not use forward declaration. Is this correct?

Comment: Since you are also accessing the `Ui::Window` class in `rule.cpp`, you also need to add an `#include "ui_window.h"` (corresponding to the uic/designer generated header) to `rule.cpp`.

Comment: Ah! But now that ui is a Ui::Window *, it does not recognize the functions in window.cpp! (e.g. ui->do_stuff() in rule.cpp returns "Class Ui::Window has no member do_stuff()"!

Comment: But ui is Ui::Window, so shouldn't be inherit of the function of Window??

Comment: Generated Ui classes only contains the widgets of Window, it isn't the window itself. But from a design point of view, Rule shouldn't have direct access to Window::ui (because it is private) or even to the Window object, because the Rule object was created by the Window object, it should have almost no knowledge about the Window object (see the (Law of Demeter)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter] ). If Rule wants to communicate something to Window it could do it with a signal or an event instead.

Comment: That's the lesson of the day I guess. Signal/event are to relationship between objects what a pointer is to passing by reference. This makes so much sense, that they don't have to know about each other. I definitely learned something very important for my coding style. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the name of your class, `Window`, is too generic and `#include <window.h>` probably includes the system one instead of yours.

Try change the clase and header name to something more specific to your app like `CardWindow`, or use `#include "window.h"`

Comment: I get exactly the same error "CardWindow has not been declared". I wonder if it is because of namespace Ui{class Window}; ? (cf window.h). Including <ui_window.h> made the error bigger, because Ui was not defined.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the namespace ui? You cannot declare a Window in namespace ui and never define it within that namespace.

Comment: I am using Qt Creator. The Ui namespace has been generated by Qt Creator. What I am trying to do is just passing a pointer to Rule::rule, so that Rule::rule can change the GUI directly without having to send back to Window::ui the change needed.

Comment: It is justified by the fact that I don't want to implement the rule of the game inside window.cpp, which is just for the GUI.

Comment: Did you also change the name of the header file to CardWindow.h?