# Segmentation fault in qt

Tags: qt

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting a segmentation fault in my printn function?

"grad.h"

```
namespace Ui {
class grad;
}

class grad : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
  explicit grad(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~grad();

private:
Ui::grad *ui;
};
```

"course.cpp"

```
void course::printr(vector<course> c){
    QString string;
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)c.size();i++){
        string = QString::fromStdString(c[i].getTitle());
        Ui::grad->textEdit->append(string);
    }
}
```

The debugger shows the correct output up until the first iteration of the for loop when it reaches the Ui::grad part. then I get a segmentation fault. Let me know if I need to post more code thanks.

Comment: Have you set up the UI? Try ui->setupUi(this); in the constructor for example.

Comment: How can that even compile? Ui::grad is a type, not an instance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if textEdit is of Class QTextEdit. If so and you just want to append the text try

```
textEdit->setText(textEdit->plainText().append(string));
```

Comment: I changed       
    `Ui::grad->textEdit->append(string);`
to
    `Ui::grad().textEdit->append("string1");`
and now it will compile without errors but gives the segmentation fault when in run the program

Answer (score 1):

`Ui::grad->textEdit->append(string);` 
Error is here, but it shouldn't compile.
 `Ui::grad` is the name of class, you cannot use operator `->` to it. You definetly need some instance of `grad` class (not `Ui::grad`, just `grad` of your namespace) to do what you want.
Also it's generally not a good idea to name classes in the same manner as objects, I think you need to use some naming convention to make this kind of errors easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

change line;

```
Ui::grad->textEdit->append(string);
```

to

```
ui->textEdit->append(string);
```

and let me know ifi it works or not.

Comment: It won't work, `course` class have no member `ui` as I can predict

Comment: yeah i didn't recognize this. he should use signals and slots to access main window members.

Comment: SpongeBobFan is right. "course" has no member ui. The application has course.h, course.cpp, grad.h and grad.cpp. The grad class was generated by qt. I coded the course class by itself in c++ and now I'm trying to tie the two together. Instead of outputting text to the console, I want it to output to a textEdit.

Comment: This post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313206/c-qt-uiwindow-and-inheritance-forward-declaration) seems to be dealing with the same problem.